# Using Pig to manipulate json file

Tags: json, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

I've called a json file into HDFS (HDF 2.4 Sandbox running on a virtual machine), and now I want to use Pig to manipulate the data within the file.

I started down the route of trying to define a schema to pass the file into Pig using JsonLoader, but abandoned this when I read somewhere that Pig can't handle multiline files, which I suspect this might be (this is my first time working with json and the data file is quite complexly structured - it's 3-hourly weather forecast data for 5 days out, sourced from the Met Office api (http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/uk-3hourly-site-specific-forecast).

My question is: what's the quickest, easiest way to simply get this data into Pig so that I can start manipulating it?

I've chanced my arm running the following script to load the file in, but as the file's only 4.3Kb, and the scripts now been running for over 15mins with no result or logs being generated, I'm concluding this approach hasn't been successful:

```
jdata = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/MetFiles/matched/BolsoverSite.json' USING PigStorage(',')
```

Greatly appreciate any guidance thanks.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the data out? DUMP jdata; will let you know if the load was successful.Also try to load into a single column jdata = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/MetFiles/matched/BolsoverSite.json' USING PigStorage() as (line:charrarray);

Comment: Thanks@inquisitive_mind When I run just the `LOAD` statement, the script completes without any errors (note a typo on `line:chararray`), but when I add the `DUMP` statement on the following line and execute the script, it throws an error: `ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/MetFiles/matched/BolsoverSite.json` Any idea why this should be? I can't understand how it can apparently load the data ok but then error just on displaying it?

Comment: Your path is incorrect.Check where the file is and provide the full path.It has not loaded and hence the error.

Comment: Ahh! Got it. Although I'd loaded the json file into HDFS, I'd saved the file name as 'BolsoverSite' and just presumed that i'd need to include the file extension as part of the input path. When I altered the input path in the script to read just `.../BolsoverSite` it worked a treat. Thanks very much for your further help.